# Database mysql trying to find out how it all connecting together, all authors that have published minimum one book with a publisher

Tags: mysql, database, select

So i got this database.

- CONSULTANT(cons_id, firstname, lastname, epost)
- BOOK(book_id, title, published_year, publisher_id*)
- PUBLISHER(publisher_id, publisher_name, adresse, phone)
- AUTHOR(author_id, firstname, lastname, birth_year, year_of_death, nationality)
- BOOK_AUTHOR(book_id*, author_id*)

I am just trying to understand how it all connect together.

I need help getting all authors that have published minimum one book with the publisher Cappelen.
I am not sure how i can show the database on this site?

UPDATED!
Was a little to fast to ask a question, forgot the code.

This is the code i have now

```
SELECT au.firstname, au.lastname, publisher_name, title
FROM author au, publisher pu, book b;
```

this gives me

[image]

So i just need a way to choose all the authors that has published on Cappelen.

Comment: Please study SQL's [JOIN operation](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) if you have not done so already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving your problem requires combining several SQL techniques.

**JOIN**: To get a resultset of authors, their books, and those books' publishers you do this.

```sql
SELECT AUTHOR.firstname, AUTHOR.lastname,
       BOOK.title, BOOK.published_year,
       PUBLISHER.publisher_name
  FROM AUTHOR
  JOIN BOOK_AUTHOR ON AUTHOR.author_id = BOOK_AUTHOR.author_id
  JOIN BOOK        ON BOOK_AUTHOR.book_id = BOOK.book_id
  JOIN PUBLISHER   ON BOOK.publisher_id = PUBLISHER.publisher_id
```

The JOIN operations declare the relationships between rows in your various tables. Give this a try. Get familiar with how JOINs work -- they put the *relational* in *relational database management system*.

(Notice there are no `id` numbers I can see that relate your `CONSULTANT` table's rows to any other tables' rows. Perhaps there is another table you haven't described? But the answer to your question does not need `CONSULTANT`.)

**COUNT**: Once you know how to get that author / book / publisher result set, then you modify it do an aggregate (COUNT / GROUP BY) query.

```sql
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT book_id) book_count,
       AUTHOR.firstname, AUTHOR.lastname,
       PUBLISHER.publisher_name
  FROM AUTHOR
  JOIN BOOK_AUTHOR ON AUTHOR.author_id = BOOK_AUTHOR.author_id
  JOIN BOOK        ON BOOK_AUTHOR.book_id = BOOK.book_id
  JOIN PUBLISHER   ON BOOK.publisher_id = PUBLISHER.publisher_id
 GROUP BY AUTHOR.firstname, AUTHOR.lastname, PUBLISHER.publisher_name
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT book_id)` gets the number of distinct (different) books for the GROUP BY AUTHOR and PUBLISHER information.

**WHERE filtering**: Finally you throw in a WHERE clause to choose just one publisher.

```sql
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT book_id) book_count,
       AUTHOR.firstname, AUTHOR.lastname,
       PUBLISHER.publisher_name
  FROM AUTHOR
  JOIN BOOK_AUTHOR ON AUTHOR.author_id = BOOK_AUTHOR.author_id
  JOIN BOOK        ON BOOK_AUTHOR.book_id = BOOK.book_id
  JOIN PUBLISHER   ON BOOK.publisher_id = PUBLISHER.publisher_id
 WHERE PUBLISHER.publisher_name = 'Cappelen'
 GROUP BY AUTHOR.firstname, AUTHOR.lastname, PUBLISHER.publisher_name
```

If you wanted to see authors with two or more books, you append `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT book_id) >= 2` to the end of that query.